# Reading sas/stata/spss import scripts with python/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've been given a large dataset with import scripts for SAS, SPSS, and Stata. Without these import scripts, bringing the datafile into Pandas just results in a bunch of unintelligible numbered column labels. Is there any good library or standard solution for reading these import scripts with python and applying them to the dataset, or should I just try to run a bunch of regexes on SAS scripts to convert them to something python-ish?

Comment: What have you tried?  How consistently formatted are the scripts? Do they not have the metadata in data format?

Comment: Can you post some of the SAS code? I'm assuming the file is a text file and the code is to read the file.

Answer (score 0):

Well `SAS` and `Stata` are quite easy to import with generally with pretty good dtype preservation, see the docs [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html)